# Запятая перед союзом "И" на стыке союзов

Tags: синтаксис

Грамоте.ру задали вопрос.

Вопрос № 287365

Добрый вечер! Проходила диктант А. А. Усачёва "Умная собачка Соня". Не могли бы вы подсказать, в соответствии с каким правилом нужна запятая перед "и" в следующем предложении: – Все воспитанные собачки, – произнесла такса, – должны быть вежливыми, и, если им дают косточку, конфетку или полезный совет, говорить «спасибо»!

**Ответ справочной службы русского языка**

Запятая перед союзом и в этом предложении не нужна, т. к. союз соединяет однородные сказуемые. В диктанте правильным признается вариант без запятой.

> Вопрос: Грамота права? Разве здесь не действует это правило?
>
> Запятая на стыке двух союзов не ставится, если после первого союза следует вторая часть двойного союза то, так, или но, наличие которой требует перестройки.

Григорий, обожжённый внезапной и радостной решимостью, с трудом удержал коня и, когда последняя сотня, едва не растоптав Степана, промчалась мимо, подскакал к нему (Ш.)

**Здесь ведь тоже можно усмотреть однородные сказуемые: удержал и подскакал.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Вопрос: Грамота права?

**Права.**

> Запятая **перед** союзом ***и*** в этом предложении не нужна...

Comment: А правило можете дать?

Comment: Не понял вас. Что приведенное мной правило?

Comment: _Рубен Г.: А правило можете дать?_ === Так Справка же сказала: _"союз **и** соединяет однородные сказуемые._  И она права. Откуда взяться запятой в этом предложении: _Все воспитанные собачки **должны быть вежливыми** и **говорить «спасибо»**!_ ?

Comment: Григорий с трудом  удержал коня и подскакал к нему.  Это не однородные сказуемые?

Comment: Конечно, однородные. И запятой **ПЕРЕД** союзом "и"  нет и в этом предложении.

Comment: Как же нету? Есть. Пример- то взят из Розенталя.

Comment: Григорий, обожжённый внезапной и радостной решимостью, с трудом удержал коня ***и ,*** когда последняя сотня, едва не растоптав Степана, промчалась мимо, подскакал к нему (Ш.)

Comment: После и не следует двойная часть союза. Поэтому стоит запятая. То же и в примере справки.

Comment: Так запятая-то в этом предложении (про Григория) стоит **ПОСЛЕ** союза "и". И стоит она потому, что после союза "и" идёт **придаточное**: _когда последняя сотня... промчалась мимо"_.

Comment: Да, я невнимательно прочитал ответ справки. Я увидел запятую после ***и*** подумал, что речь идет об этой запятой.

Comment: Слава, на этом же сайте, в подобном примере один из участников ( Виктор)  говорит о запятой перед именно перед ***и*** в подобном примере. Я согласен с вами, но ответ участника меня запутал.

Comment: Вбейте это предложения ( из Розенталя) в поисковике сайта и посмотрите, пожалуйста. А то я уже запутался.

Comment: Ладно, уже не надо. Сам разобрался. Спасибо большое.